# What does &.!= mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
action&.!=:click
```

Can somebody please explain to me what is the meaning of this in ruby and where I can get some explanations? I try to search ruby documentation, but no luck with this kind of 'chaining' operators

`:click` is symbol

`!=` is not equal

but I have no idea about `&.`

Comment: https://aaronlasseigne.com/2016/01/04/rubys-new-safe-navigation-not-equal-operator/

Comment: That's a terrible way to write `action && action != :click`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What looks like one operator in the middle (`&.!=`) is actually 1 operator and 1 method call : [`&.`](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) followed by [`!=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-21-3D) with `:click` as argument:

```
action &. != :click
```

It checks if `action` is not `nil` but distinct from `:click`:

```
action = nil
action&.!=:click
# => nil

action = :not_click
action&.!=:click
# => true

action = :click
action&.!=:click
# => false

action = false
action&.!=:click
# => true
```

It's an abusive way to use `&.` in my humble opinion. `&.` is called a "safe navigation operator", because it prevents you from calling undefined methods on `nil` objects.

`!=` is defined for any object though, so there's nothing safe about using `&.` before `!=`.

You could write :

```
!(action.nil? || action == :click)
```

or

```
!action.nil? && action != :click
```

or even:

```
![nil, :click].include?(action)
```

Comment: Wait, how did your answer get through the dup close?

Comment: Did you start composing it _before_ I closed it?

Comment: "is actually 2 operators" - _actually_ it is one operator and one method call :) If we count `&.` as operator, that is.